# How to handle redirects for two different domains w/ diff. hierarchies in one .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables

I've got a series of websites, each one of which lives in two locations, 1) A Dev environment, 2) The production environment.  The two are structured slightly differently.

In the Dev environment: **www.devdomain.com/sitename/**

In the production environment: **www.productiondomain.com/**

The goal is to have .htaccess handle non-existant paths such that when the path is missing, the site re-directs to root and passes the missing path as an environmental variable.

So something along these lines...

```
RewriteEngine On
#The following is necessary to for the final line to process correctly on the dev domain but causes problems on the production domain.
RewriteBase /sitename/

#Capture the intended path in an environment variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]

#redirect non-existant path
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \#$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

The above is not working for a number of reasons

1 - The first line doesn't seem to capture the intended path but rather the path as written by the final line

2 - The final path (currently) re-writes the non-existant part of the path as a hash (which is cool, but I'd prefer the non-existant path passed as an environment variable)

3 - The RewriteBase works on the dev domain, but not on the production domain.

———

I tried re-doing the final line as `RewriteRule %{SERVER_NAME}` but for non-existant paths I get the error: "The requested URL was not found on this server".

Additional Question: The "$1" in the final line seems like a regexp group capture.  Is that correct?  How does it inherit its value?

Comment: _“The two are structured slightly differently.”_ - why though? I find it always best to _match_ the two environments as closely as possible, that usually leads to the least amount of trouble and surprises. If at all possible, I’d set this up as `sitename.devdomain.com`, and then use the same rewrite configuration for both, based on the same structure.

Comment: `%{SERVER_NAME}` might not be what you think it is. If anything, this should use `%{HTTP_HOST}` - that is the host name that was used in the request.

Comment: The `$1` gets is value from the capturing part in the pattern - `(.*)`

Comment: RE matching environments -- not an option

Comment: RE `%{SERVER_NAME}` vs `%{HTTP_HOST}` - on this particular machine both hold the same value: 'localhost'

Comment: RE $1 -- Thanks -- so it captures the value from the same line, never from another line of .htaccess, correct?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule - `$N` refers back to a capture group from the RewriteRule pattern, `%N` to those of the last matched RewriteCond pattern.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks again for clarifying and for the link. Slowly by slowly figuring out htaccess.